# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have using jQuery Mobile v1.5.0 to make menu open on swipe all is working fine but this error is always there, i have try to add addEventListener example:

```
// open menu on swipe to right
$(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {
    document.addEventListener("swiperight", e.preventDefault(), {passive: false} );
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.menu').addClass('active');
});
```

But error is still there

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.
```

Code:

```
// open menu on swipe to right
$(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.menu').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Well, I'm very confused how you would have an event to prevent in the first snippet if it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: I have added it under ``$(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {``

Comment: Wait, are you saying your putting the `document.addEventListener` call **in** the bottom snippet?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Yeah, no don't do that.  You're creating an event handler inside another event handler.  Why do you feel like you need to do that?

Comment: Because i asked , not sure how to fix

Answer (score 7):

FYI: in my case (using Owl Carousel) the fix to me was pure css:

```
.owl-carousel {
    touch-action: manipulation; 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, added to the scrolling element. The problem appears when jQueryMobile is loaded and I have an element with "overflow: scroll".

Answer (score 6):

No need to add another `eventListener`. This error may be solved using CSS. Add `touch-action: none;` to the container which You are swiping.

> Here is a **DEMO** using an external JQM Panel as global navigation
>   menu:

```js
$(document)
  .on('swiperight', '#page-acura, #page-audi, #page-bmw', function(e) {
    $("#panel").panel("open");
  })
  .ready(function() {
    $("#panel").panel({theme: "a", display: "overlay"}).enhanceWithin();
  });
```

```css
.ui-page,
.ui-panel,
.ui-panel-wrapper,
.ui-panel-dismiss {
  touch-action: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JQM 1.5.0 RC1 Panel Menu</title>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, width=device-width, minimal-ui shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-acura">
      <div class="ui-toolbar-header ui-body-a">
        <h2 class="ui-toolbar-title">Acura</h2>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Acura content goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-toolbar-footer ui-toolbar-footer-fixed ui-body-a">
        <h2 class="ui-toolbar-title">Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-audi">
      <div class="ui-toolbar-header ui-body-a">
        <h2 class="ui-toolbar-title">Audi</h2>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Audi content goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-toolbar-footer ui-toolbar-footer-fixed ui-body-a">
        <h2 class="ui-toolbar-title">Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-bmw">
      <div class="ui-toolbar-header ui-body-a">
        <h2 class="ui-toolbar-title">BMW</h2>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>BMW content goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-toolbar-footer ui-toolbar-footer-fixed ui-body-a">
        <h2 class="ui-toolbar-title">Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#page-acura">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-audi">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page-bmw">BMW</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```